# Using createSelector with useSelector and a selector from another file whats the correct syntax?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a selector setup in my reducer file, and in my react file I want to use useReducer and createSelector to call that selector only when part of the state (state.data) changes

// Selector in reducer.js

```
const getScore = (state = initialState) => 
  Object.values(state.data).reduce(
    (score, { status }) =>
      status === "accepted" ? score + 1 : 
      status === "rejected" ? score + 10 : 
      score, 0
  );
```

// Call from reactComponent.js

```
const score = useSelector(({ rejectionState }) => getScore(rejectionState));
```

What should the syntax for createSelector be and the changes to the syntax for useSelector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with `rejectionState` here, but I'm assuming that the `data` located at `state.rejectionState.data` rather than `state.data`.

You want one function which selects the `data` from the store, and one function which maps the `data` to a score.  Then you use `createSelector` to combine the two.  You can define those functions separately as variables or write them directly inside `createSelector`.

```js
const {createSelector} = Reselect;

const dataSelector = (state) => state.rejectionState.data;

const getScore = (data = {}) =>
  Object.values(data).reduce(
    (score, { status }) =>
      status === "accepted"
        ? score + 1
        : status === "rejected"
        ? score + 10
        : score,
    0
  );

const scoreSelector = createSelector(dataSelector, getScore);

let exampleState = {
  rejectionState: {
    data: {
      someKey: {
        status: "accepted"
      },
      otherKey: {
        status: "rejected"
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log( "exampleState score is:" )
console.log( scoreSelector(exampleState) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/3.0.1/reselect.js"></script>
```